# Cuda kernel time measurement with CudaEventElapsedTime

Tags: visual-c++, time, cuda, gpu, execution-time

I've got NVS 5400M and I'm trying to get reliable time measurement results for cuda addition on matrix (instance 1000 x 1000).

```
__global__ void MatAdd(int** A, int** B, int** C) {
int i = threadIdx.x;
int j = threadIdx.y;
C[i][j] = A[i][j] + B[i][j]; }
```

And I'm doing measurement like:

```
int numBlocks = 1;
dim3 threadsPerBlock(1000, 1000);

float time;
cudaEvent_t start, stop;
cudaEventCreate(&start);
cudaEventCreate(&stop);
cudaEventRecord(start, 0);

MatAdd <<<numBlocks, threadsPerBlock>>>(pA, pB, pC);

cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);

cout << setprecision(10) << "GPU Time [ms] " << time << endl;
```

and the result is: 0.001504000043 ms, which is relatively small. My question is am I doing it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your timing is correct, but your usage of CUDA in general is not.

This is illegal:

```
dim3 threadsPerBlock(1000, 1000);
```

CUDA kernels are limited to a maximum of 1024 threads per block, but you are requesting 1000x1000 = 1,000,000 threads per block.

As a result, your kernel is not actually launching:

```
MatAdd <<<numBlocks, threadsPerBlock>>>(pA, pB, pC);
```

And so the measured time is quite short.

You are advised to use [proper cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) and run your tests with `cuda-memcheck` to make sure there are no reported runtime errors (my guess is right now you are not even aware of the errors being reported from your code - you have to check for them.)

Since you haven't shown a complete code, I'm not going to try to identify all other issues that may be present, but your kernel code would have to be re-factored in order to handle a 1000x1000 array properly, and passing double-pointer (e.g. `int** A`) parameters to kernels is considerably more difficult than a single pointer or "flat" array.

Comment: After checking cudError_t I reveived message: sync kernel error: invalid configuration argument. 

Thank you!

Comment: @Edit: I've changed to `dim3 threadsPerBlock(32, 32)`
and the actual code is: 
`int** A = create_random_matrix(1000);`
`int** pA = initialize_matrix(1000);`
`cudaMalloc((void**)pA, (1000*1000)*sizeof(int));`
`cudaMemcpy(pA, A, (1000*1000)*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice)`
the same for B & C, and after that 
`MatAdd <<<numBlocks, threadsPerBlock >>>(pA, pB, pC);`
`cudaMemcpy(C, pC, (1000*1000)*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);`
and received: invalid argument & illegal memory acces was encoutered

Comment: the illegal memory access is because you don't understand how to manage double-pointer arguments to kernels correctly.  It will require a deep copy.  For simplicity, I would suggest flattening your arrays so they can be referenced with a single subscript.   If you want help with a code that you haven't shown and a new problem, I suggest posting a new question.